# Chromosomal disorders

Tags: genetics, chromosome

I was reading about chromosomal disorders and encountered a line stating that

> 'An individual may lack one of **any one** pair of chromosomes'

So does it mean that an individual cannot have monosomy of two different chromosome pairs? Or does it has some other meaning. Please Help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not a forum or tutorial service; it is a Q&A site where *specific* questions relating to biology get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask] a good question. In particular, we can't "explain" random quotes — which will be opinion (and thus off-topic). Finally quotes must always include a source!

Answer (score 2):

The only "complete" monosomy that is survivable in humans is Turner syndrome.

So your source is a bit silly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosomy

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically anything can happen, but you also have to take into account firstly, the probability of such an incident (which is particularly rare in this case) and secondly, if the creature can survive after or even until birth, to be counted as an organism with that kind of anomaly. For instance, the odds of trisomy 21 taking place in humans is not much greater than that of trisomy 11, but almost all fetuses with trisomy 11 would be aborted and never make it to this world.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.